# JSON Web Token with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rack, jwt

I hope this does not count as an opinionated question. I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

I am modifying the `Devise` gem to work purely with `JSON`. I have had no problems with the `registration`, `confirmation`, `re-confirmation`, `locking` so far.

However, while working with the sign in, I dug deeper and understand that the default `Devise` sign in strategy uses `Warden` as it has to do with sessions and `Rack` authentication.

I understand `JWT` contains all the information in itself and does not need sessions.

So if I strip the default `Devise` strategy of everything and simply return a `JWT` on success and errors on error, would that be the right approach?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 12):

In order to use JWT with devise, I recommend to not monkey patch devise and instead use a tool others can audit and test.

For this reason, I developed [devise-jwt](https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt). It does zero monkey patching and leverages warden, which is the authentication library below devise. You can also read more about it in this post I wrote: [A Secure JWT Authentication Implementation for Rack and Rails](http://waiting-for-dev.github.io/blog/2017/01/26/a_secure_jwt_authentication_implementation_for_rack_and_rails)

Hope it helps

Comment: sorry, page not found.

Comment: Thanks for reporting. Fixed, the link is working now.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't use `devise_token_auth` since it seems like too much hassle and ... you store tokens in db :/. Why would we want to do so if JWT is available.

I'd rather add a new strategy to Warden/Devise couple and let them work as they should.

Here's an example: https://medium.com/@goncalvesjoao/rails-devise-jwt-and-the-forgotten-warden-67cfcf8a0b73 . One thing to note: JWTWrapper doesn't really belong to `app/helpers/` . You need to inject somewhere a call to `JWTWrapper.encode({ user_id: current_user.id })` once your users successfully signs in with their email/password. Perhaps in the Devise SessionsController?

```
def create
  self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  yield resource if block_given?
  render json: JWTWrapper.encode({user_id:current_user.id})
end
```

You might want to do this only for xhr or json (format) requests

Answer (score 3):

You probably shouldn't be hacking your Devise gem source. I suggest to just use **Devise Token Auth** gem to handle tokens instead.

https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth

It will generate and authenticate valid [RFC 6750 Bearer Tokens](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750).

According to their README.

- Seamless integration with both the the venerable ng-token-auth module for angular.js and the outstanding jToker plugin for jQuery.
- Oauth2 authentication using OmniAuth.
- Email authentication using Devise, including:

  - User registration
  - Password reset
  - Account updates
  - Account deletion

  Support for multiple user models.

  It is **secure**.

Comment: I have been pointed to that gem by a lot of people but this does not answer my question. Would a pure `JWT` implementation require anything to do with `Warden` and `Sessions`?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late answer, but I'm actually working on the same problem, and want to share my opinions on that.

First, I would emphasize not changing Davise sources, this will likely bring you to further problems, especially when Devise code changes.

On the other hand, as I have encountered devise-token-auth, it might not be viable for your needs, especially in distributed systems (SOA). Perhaps I'm wrong, but as I see devise-token-auth, you can't add `Subjects` to restrict user access solely on the token. If you don't need this feature, you really should try devise-token-auth.

If you want to store additional information in the token, you could try to authenticate against a regular devise or devise-token-auth and then encode your information using a JWT gem.

Example can be found here: https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-to-using-jwt-in-rails/